# How to restore functionality while drawing vertices?

Tags: vertices

Yesterday, I watched ianscott888 tutorial on drawing vertices. Great video. And for several hours afterwards, I was gleefully drawing verts on new projects and old. It worked fantastic. ***Then, it stopped working***.

So, I went to every extreme to get the functionality back. Even reloaded Blender to make sure I had a good version.

Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>. That's how it's supposed to work. But, now all I get is faint gray area bordered by white dots. Can you please help me figure out if this is a Blender problem or something I've done wrong? Will provide screenshot if allowed.

Comment: By default Ctrl+RMB is used for selecting shortest path between first and last selected pieces of geometry. Ctrl+LMB should work for extruding (as I assume you mean extruding by drawing new vertices)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to stop moving your mouse when you click.

In edit mode <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB]</kbd> is a shortcut to [extrude](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/adding.html#duplicate-or-extrude-to-cursor), the selected vertices will be extruded to the point you click.

Holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> while dragging the <kbd>[image: LMB]</kbd> is the way to use [lasso select](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/selecting/tools.html#lasso-select). This is what gives you the grey area surrounded by dots.

Note that this is based on blenders default <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> [to select option](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/input.html), by changing that to <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> you get the same result by using <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. I also discovered that you can create a vertex by CTRL + LMB. Then, E to extrude. No more lasso.